# Connection refused error for kube-dns pod

Tags: networking, container, kubernetes

I have configured kubernet v1.9.3 in my Ubuntu 16.04LTS system. Master node was successfully created with an exception of kube-dns pod getting a connection refused issue.

I am getting the following exception in the logs:

```
Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503
Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.244.0.6:8081/readiness: dial tcp 10.244.0.6:8081: getsockopt: connection refused
```

I have installed following flannel packages for networking:

```
clusterrole "flannel" created
clusterrolebinding "flannel" created
serviceaccount "flannel" created
configmap "kube-flannel-cfg" created
daemonset "kube-flannel-ds" created
```

Need to know why I am getting this connection refused error.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try below command :

`kubectl apply -f https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/v0.8.0/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml -f https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/v0.8.0/Documentation/kube-flannel-rbac.yml`

then try to list pods and check logs for kube-dns pod

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what these commands are doing? Randomly executing commands from strangers on the internet is not only extremely dangerous, it also doesn't help with getting ontop of the problem itself.